# Get nativeImage dimensions

Tags: electron

I have a `nativeImage` but am not able to figure out it's width and height. Is this possible? I can't find anything here - https://electronjs.org/docs/api/native-image#imagegetaspectratio

Answer (score 0):

I see `getSize` in the [API documentation](https://xwartz.gitbooks.io/electron-gitbook/content/en/api/native-image.html).